# how to get memory address of kernel32.dll!BaseThreadStartThunk?

Tags: c++, memory-address

i see in procexp some threads that have a starting address `kernel32.dll+0x106e9` ,after resolving symbols, i get the address: `kernel32.dll!BaseThreadStartThunk`

i want to enumerate all thread in the system and print the threads with this starting address, but when i try to get the address of `BaseThreadStartThunk`, by:

```
PVOID BaseThreadStartThunk_addr = GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"Kernel32.dll"), "BaseThreadStartThunk");
```

i get back 0

how can i get the address of `BaseThreadStartThunk()`?

Comment: I'd try `GetModuleHandle` instead of `LoadLibrary`. Also function pointers may have a different size than `PVOID`, the Windows headers offer the type `PROC` for this.

Comment: Does not help, besides, GetModuleHandle(L"Kernel32.dll") and LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll") Return the same value 75680000

Comment: It's likely that this symbol is not exported by `kernel32.dll` symbol table. In fact this looks very much like the name of an internal function related to thread management. You'll have a hard time to resolve such with `GetProcAddress`; when you resolve the symbols with a debugger, the debugger loads an external symbol database, provided by Microsoft so that in case of a problem that touches the core of the OS you can deliver meaningful bug reports to the Microsoft developers.

Comment: if so, how can i go the other way, from the thread base address to the symbol name? i can enum all the thread addresses and resolve for every address the symbol, am i correct? how to do that?

Comment: I suggest you look into the SymFromAddr function. It requires the debug symbols to be installed on your system though, so you should not use it in end user releases, because your Average Joe doesn't have the debug symbols installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetProcAddress is implementation of parsing of EAT (Export Address Table), this function try find name or ordinal in EAT, then get delta to function from module base and add this delta with module base.

if "BaseThreadStartThunk" is not exported symbol, then GetProcAddress cannot get it.

You can:

1. use pdb symbols for resolve name and get it delta from module base (need internet for load symbols on each PC)
2. create binary signature of "BaseThreadStartThunk" and find it in memory
3. create table with "kernel32 version", "function delta" - make hardcoded delta to func for each version of kernel32
4. use disassembler for find address of function - i think, this is best way